# Which property or method returns the number of connections active/closed/in-progress status in ASP.Net Core MVC 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework 2.2.4 in .Net Core v2.2. By using max pool size with AddDbContextPool method to create 1000 connections. It is an Asp .Net core MVC application. We are getting an exception that max pool size reached and that causing the time-out while executing stored procedure (connected to SQL Server).

Query is: Is there any method or property that returns the total number of connections created and in progress, Open and Close state. By using Database.GetDbConnection() method, a new connection is to be pulled from the connection pool.

Please suggest.

Comment: I believe this might be what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809073/how-to-check-current-pool-size-of-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking for Performance Counters in Entity framework .net core. I want to know, is there any way to get the current pool size during the execution of the application.

Comment: Did you take a look at performance counter info in the link I sent?

Comment: Perhaps, I missed something but not sure. I had seen the information related to ADO.Net  performance counters. As to reiterate, I need the same in the EF Core v2.2;

Comment: Whilst not 100% sure, I would imagine they'd use the same performance counters since EF is an abstraction of your data layer and most (if not all) MS performance counters come from WMI.